# MVC Application Template Provided Rounded Corners Go Away When Site Published

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I created an MVC 3 (w/ 3.0 Tools Update) web site based on the Intranet Application template.  When I run it from VS on my machine the Home/About buttons are rounded.  But when I publish the site to my IIS Server (Win 2008 Server / IIS 7.0) and view the site, the rounded corners are gone.  Any ideas on how I can get the rounded corners to work when published?

Comment: Does this have something to do with the CSS border-radius property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you tell us what browsers you're using to view the site?

If you're using IE, it might be rendering in IE8/9 mode when you're debugging, but be rendering in compat mode when you visit the site internally.

You can fix that by adding the following tag to your head.

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

If you see the same issues using FF try clearing your temporary internet files. Your stylesheet might've been cached.